# Generate the AWS HTTP signature from boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto, botocore

I am working with the [AWS Transcribe streaming](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/how-streaming.html) service that boto3 does not support yet, so to make HTTP/2 requests, I need to manually setup the `authorization` header with the "AWS Signature Version 4"

I've found some example [implementation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html), but I was hoping to just call whatever function boto3/botocore have implemented using the same configuration object.

Something like

```
    session = boto3.Session(...)
    auth = session.generate_signature('POST', '/stream-transcription', ...)
```

Any pointers in that direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check this SDK? Seems very recent but might do what you need.

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-transcribe-streaming-sdk/tree/master

It looks like it handles the signing: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-transcribe-streaming-sdk/blob/master/amazon_transcribe/signer.py

Comment: Wow, this was literally created this week. I will check for sure.

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to the AWS SDKs for most other programming languages, `boto3`/`botocore` don't offer the functionality to sign arbitrary requests using "AWS Signature Version 4" yet.  However there is at least already an open feature request for that: https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1784

In this feature request, existing alternatives are discussed as well. One is the third-party Python library [`aws-requests-auth`](https://github.com/davidmuller/aws-requests-auth), which provides a thin wrapper around `botocore` and `requests` to sign HTTP-requests. That looks like the following:

```py
import requests
from aws_requests_auth.boto_utils import BotoAWSRequestsAuth

auth = BotoAWSRequestsAuth(aws_host="your-service.domain.tld",
                           aws_region="us-east-1",
                           aws_service="execute-api")
response = requests.get("https://your-service.domain.tld",
                        auth=auth)
```

Another alternative presented in the feature request is to implement the necessary glue-code on your own, as shown in the following gist: https://gist.github.com/rhboyd/1e01190a6b27ca4ba817bf272d5a5f9a.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but you can likely accomplish this by following along with with this SigV4 unit test:

https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/master/tests/unit/test_auth_sigv4.py

Note, this constructs a request using the `botocore.awsrequest.AWSRequest` helper. You'll likely need to dig around to figure out how to send the actual HTTP request (perhaps with [httpsession.py](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/master/botocore/httpsession.py))